# Unneeded generic parameter

Tags: java, generics, coding-style

Suppose there is a requirement to use a particular generic interface, but the situation does not require making use of one of the generic parameters.

Let's say I need a [`Callable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) (which must return a `T` from its `call()` method), but on this occasion I don't need the return result, I just want to submit some code to an `ExecutorService` to "do something"

What's the best option for the type `T`?

Comment: +1 It's raining *hats questions* on stackoverflow :P

Comment: @Raffaele Was it *that* obvious? lol

Comment: It was :P especially from 0.05% top users eheh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the special [`Void`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) type:

```
Callable<Void> callable = new Callable<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        // do stuff
        return null;
    }
};
```

The `return` statement is required to exit the method. The only value which the compiler accepts is `null`. Quite handy!

Comment: the same is true of, say, `Math`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Void`.

30char30char30char, sorry, not much to add :P

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can also submit a `Runnable` to an `ExecutorService`, which does not have a return type.